# How to add overflow:visible to tooltip if parent is overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have this structure of html:

```
<h2 title="{{children.name}}">{{children.name | slice:0:45 }}{{ children.name.length > 45 ? '...':'' }} 
    <div class="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
         <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip texdasjkdshjk dhasjkd haskd haskd haskjdh askdh ashkdjah jkds t</span>
    </div>
</h2>
```

On `h2` I have `overflow:hidden`. But problem is then that I don't see full `tooltip` message. Any suggestion how can I do that?

This is my css:

```
h2{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 2px;
    pointer-events: all;
    z-index: 999999999;
    i{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: lightblue;
    }
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the attribute relative to static to h2 element  in the CSS

Comment: then position:absoulte of tooltip will not be connected with h2 position:relative

Comment: It´s true, I think the way would be wrap the elements in a layer